# Solving count query issue

Tags: php, sql

I have the following code where i need to select all items from personabisna table and count items with the same personalbisnaId from another table where the both tables share the personalbisnaid

```
 $query="select c.BusinessLogo,
                    c.PersonalBisnaId, 
                    c.account_id,
                      AS Ads from personalbisna As c INNER JOIN myads AS b on b.PersonalBisnaId=c.PersonalBisnaId GROUP BY c.PersonalBisnaId LIMIT $itemfrom,$dataperpage";
```

These are the tables

Personalbisna table

```
| PersonalBisnaId| account_id| BusinessLogo
---------------------------------------------
|       1         |   23     |  qwertyu.jpg
|       2         |    4     |  asdfghjk.jpg
|       3         |   12     |  34567gfd.jpg
|       4         |   34     |   drtyujhv.jpg
```

myads table

```
|   MyAdsId       | PersonalBisnaId| AdType
---------------------------------------------
|       1         |     2           |  logo
|       2         |     2           |  business card
|       3         |     3           |  logo
|       4         |     2           |   caricalture
```

I have used some already answered questions to solve my problem and i'm really getting totally confused to solve my issue

The above query should output the following

```
| PersonalBisnaId| account_id| BusinessLogo      | AdsCount
-------------------------------------------------------
|       1         |   23     |  qwertyu.jpg      |  0
|       2         |    4     |  asdfghjk.jpg     |  3
|       3         |   12     |  34567gfd.jpg     |  1  
|       4         |   34     |   drtyujhv.jpg    |  0
```

This what i have

```
$query="SELECT  
                c.BusinessLogo,
                c.PersonalBisnaId, 
                c.account_id,
                c.BusinessName,
                c.BusinessCategory,
                c.BusinessSubCategory,
                c.town,
                c.estate,
                c.street,
                c.road,
                c.building,
                c.Address,
                c.city,
                c.PhoneNumber,
                c.AltPhoneNumber,
                c.website,
                c.Email,
                c.BusinessType              
                COUNT(MyAdsId)  AS AdsCount
                FROM   personalbisna AS c 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN myads AS b 
                ON  b.PersonalBisnaId= c.PersonalBisnaId 
                GROUP BY  c.PersonalBisnaId LIMIT $itemfrom,$dataperpage";
```

Comment: You could show what is your desire output. And usually is nice include what is your RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

`Count` aggregate is missing in your query.

Also if you want select all items from `Personabisna` table then instead of `INNER JOIN` you need to `Left/Right Outer Join`

```
SELECT          c.personalbisnaid, 
                c.account_id,
                c.BusinessLogo,
                Count(AdType)      AS AdsCount 
FROM            personalbisna AS c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN myads         AS b 
ON              b.personalbisnaid=c.personalbisnaid 
GROUP BY        c.personalbisnaid, 
                c.account_id,
                c.BusinessLogo
```

Comment: Thanks but i need to count from myads table

Comment: @xtech - can you add the expected output in question

Comment: The output should display . 1.personalBisnaId = 3 Ads,2.personalBisnaId = 2 Ads,3.personalBisnaId = 8 Ads

Comment: @xtech - can you add that in question

Comment: I have added the expected output

Comment: @xtech - Thats exactly my query is doing. Updated with other columns check now

Comment: Okey FireBlade let me work on it then i will give you the feedback

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Count(*) AS count_personalbisnaid FROM personalbisna AS c ' at line 19

Comment: I have edited the question again showing what fully i have included on my code

Comment: @xtech - Between `..c.BusinessType              
                COUNT(MyAdsId)  AS AdsCount...` comma is missing change it to `..c.BusinessType ,             
                COUNT(MyAdsId)  AS AdsCount..`